# Is CSS3 fully enabled in every browser?

Tags: css

I'm learning CSS and there is some prefix like -moz and -webkit that repeats the same code to accomodate for Mozilla, Safari, etc. when it comes to things like CSS3 transition or border-radius.

All the answers I have found are from 2010 or 2011 but nothing recent. Do I still need to use these prefixes or are most browsers all CSS3 ready?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS3 specification itself is [incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637901/is-css3-an-official-standard/8637917#8637917), so it cannot possibly be "fully enabled" in any browser at the moment. It probably won't reach widespread standardization for another few years, especially given its granular modularization, but I suppose we're getting there.

If you need any sources from the past month, here you go:

- [How do I find out when I can safely drop vendor prefixes for a CSS3 property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211602/how-do-i-find-out-when-i-can-safely-drop-vendor-prefixes-for-a-css3-property)
- [Do we have to use non-standard/browser specific CSS vendor prefixes anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401830/do-we-have-to-use-non-standard-browser-specific-css-vendor-prefixes-anymore)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Guess I'll have to keep using the prefixes just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

in the last [3 months of statistics](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201112-201202-bar) from statcounter, there are still old browsers that have limited CSS3 support (notably IE8 and older). And CSS3 is rolled out in [a modular fashion](http://www.css3.info/modules/) so as to not give "shock-and-awe" to browser as well as web developers - in short, we're not using the full CSS3 *yet*. for browsers that are still "testing" their CSS3 styles but are at least worthy of trying, they release them with the vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, most (if not all) modern browsers support portions of the CSS3 specification. If you want to know what parts of it is supported in which browsers, I'd be lead to believe this site provides a good reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some really great resources out there for checking browser support for the individual properties and modules in CSS3/HTML5.

Check out:

- [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/),
- [CSS3 Please](http://css3please.com/),
- [HTML5 Please](http://html5please.com/)

For up-to-date information on what is supported where.