# Why can’t I seem to use background-clip?

Tags: css

My attempt to use `background-clip: content-box` is failing. The entire box has a background, including the padding area, not just the content area.

http://jsfiddle.net/alanhogan/7YjCV/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a common gotcha with shorthand properties in CSS.

Because [`background-clip` is one of the properties that's set by the `background` shorthand property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background), your `background` style is implicitly setting `background-clip` to `border-box` (its initial value), overriding your explicit `background-clip` style:

```css
background-clip: content-box;
background: #ddd none /* border-box */;
```

If you move your `background-clip` declaration beneath `background`, it'll work as expected:

```css
background: #ddd none;
background-clip: content-box;
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/7YjCV/12)

Comment: Thanks. Crazy. I understand shortcut properties & exactly how this works, but given that the `background` shortcut property has been around *forever*, it was pretty much inconceivable to me that it was expanded/redefined to now include properties that didn’t even use to exist!

Comment: @Alan H.: Well, the thing is, CSS is versioned in *levels*, where new features are added and sometimes existing ones refined — so when new properties are added, it's only appropriate that the new versions of shorthand properties are expanded to include those new properties. See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#css-levels Likewise, some *selectors* like `:not()` will also be enhanced to accept a wider range of selectors in CSS4.

Comment: See also: [Is CSS3 an official standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637901/is-css3-an-official-standard/8637917#8637917)

Answer (score 3):

The `background` CSS property is a one-line way to define *all* background properties, including `background-clip`. Thus, specifying `background: #ddd` unsets your earlier setting of `background-clip`. If instead you replace that line with `background-color: #ddd`, it should work the way you want it to.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/dvidby0/spnkf/) the small modification to your jsfiddle.

Comment: Much appreciate your answer :)