# CSS3 background-clip not working for transparent borders

Tags: css, transparency, border

I am following the [transparent border tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/) at CSS-Tricks. However, my code does not render the border transparent. My code (to my eyes) looks correct.

Please [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26795/1/)

```
#popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 20px;

    -moz-background-clip: padding; 
    -webkit-background-clip: padding;  
    background-clip: padding-box;     

    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    background: white;
}​
```

You can see on css-tricks [example page](http://css-tricks.com/examples/TransparentBorders/) that they don't require any double wrapped div tricks. They just set the div background to white, the border to transparent and specify a clip area of padding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I seem to use background-clip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455465/why-cant-i-seem-to-use-background-clip)

Comment: @BoltClock - thank you, this is indeed the problem

Answer (score 2):

Swap the order of `background` and `border-color` see:

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/26795/4/

Comment: The tutorial did not require wrapping their content with an inner div and setting it to white. This is a workaround, but not the solution I am looking for. http://css-tricks.com/examples/TransparentBorders/

Comment: Or rather, swap the order of `background` and `background-clip`.

Comment: Not trying to get in the way, but that fiddle renders perfectly to me, and he hasn't changed the html in any way (I assume you don't want to do this).