# CSS shorthand attribute with gaps

Tags: html, css, shorthand

Are CSS shorthands like `background` property working with a value-gap? I tried it with background. I wanted to set some background values static and the backgorund image dynamicly.

I did the following:

```
background: no-repeat contain center;
```

The `background-image` should be added later dynamicly. Did i something wrong? The shorthand like i used isn't working. Do i have to use the single attributes (`background-repeat, background-size, background-position` ...) to realise that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't the missing background-image. The problem is with the background-size and background-position values. Unlike the rest of the longhands, values for those two have a very specific grammar: background-position followed by a `/` followed by background-size. See the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background).

This is what it should look like:

```
background: no-repeat center / contain;
```

You can always set a background-image separately.

Some other shorthands do have mandatory values. For example, [`font`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-prop) requires a font-size and a font-family. `background` does not have any mandatory values.

Comment: Working like a charm! Thank you!!

Comment: Slightly off-topic: love writing `background:0 /cover;` instead of `background-size:cover;`. I do it every chance i get. And, before you say it, I know in theory it's slower, because of shorthand vs regular :)

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu: As long as you're not unintentionally [overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455465/why-can-t-i-seem-to-use-background-clip/10455580#10455580) any [longhands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950632/firefox-and-chrome-ignoring-background-size/15951751#15951751) ;)