# CSS3 selector for "not A and not B"?

Tags: css, css-selectors, boolean-logic

I have this code which makes every paragraph with class different than "`cl2`" red.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p{ color:#000000; }
:not(.cl2){ color:#ff0000; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="cl1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="cl2">This is second paragraph.</p>
<p class="cl2">This is third paragraph.</p>
<p class="cl3">This is fourth paragraph.</p>
<p class="cl2">This is fifth paragraph.</p>
<p class="cl2">This is sixth paragraph.</p>
<p class="cl4">This is seventh paragraph.</p>
<p class="cl5">This is eigth paragraph.</p>
<p class="cl1">This is nineth paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

How can I extend my `:not` selector to ignore for example classes "`cl2`" AND "`cl4`"? I trided: `:not(.cl2, .cl4){ color:#ff0000; }` but it doesn't work.

Comment: CSS only supports conjunctions via `XY`, where `X` and `Y` represent selectors (e.g. `.cl2.cl4`), AFAIK. Is it possible to do `:not(.cl2):not(.cl4)` in CSS3?

Comment: @pst: [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403129/combining-not-selectors-in-css) ([see also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
:not(.cl2):not(.cl4){ color:#ff0000; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nottrobin/WFwtP/

Note there are [differences between the `:not` selector in CSS3 vs jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css) - due to converge in the CSS4 spec (thanks @BoltClock)

Comment: The reason why you have to do this is because `:not(.cl2, .cl4)` is not valid in CSS3, however it is valid in jQuery and proposed for CSS4. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css).

Comment: Thanks I didn't know it was valid jQuery syntax, and I didn't even know CSS4 was a thing. Awesome.

Comment: Apparently [CSS4 is not a thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637901/is-css3-an-official-standard/8637917#8637917) (and that was *my* mistake). I was really referring to Selectors 4 :)